# Mysql Rewrite Column with JSON Array

Tags: mysql, json

I want to write an MySQL Query where I replace a JSON Array with Data from another Table.

I have got two Tables, "Reserved" and "Seats". Reserved contains one column "Seats", an JSON Array referring to the ID of the Table "Seats". Table Seats also contains a column "Name". I now want to basically replace the IDs in the JSON Data of the Seats column of the Reserved Table, with the name of the corresponding IDs stored in the Seats Table.

Is there a way to do this in an Mysql Query. I do not know how to pack a query result in a JSON Format and return it as a column
I already tried to utilize JSON_EXTRACT somehow : see test below.

```
SELECT * FROM `seats` WHERE ID = JSON_EXTRACT('["276", "277", "278"]','$.*')
```

Basically I want a Query like this:

```
SELECT *, 
JSONCreate(SELECT name from `seats` WHERE seats.id IN JSON_EXTRACT(reserved.seats)) as name  
FROM `reserved` 
WHERE 1
```

Comment: Have you read about [JSON_ARRAY()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-creation-functions.html#function_json-array) and [JSON_ARRAYAGG()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)? One of these probably does what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of the following solutions.

**solution using [`JSON_SEARCH`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-search) and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)**

```
SELECT r.seats, JSON_ARRAYAGG(s.name)
FROM reserved r JOIN seats s ON JSON_SEARCH(r.seats, 'one', CONVERT(s.id, CHAR(10))) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY r.seats
```

**solution using [`... MEMBER OF ()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#operator_member-of) and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)**

```
SELECT r.seats, JSON_ARRAYAGG(s.name)
FROM reserved r INNER JOIN seats s ON CONVERT(s.id, CHAR) MEMBER OF(r.seats)
GROUP BY r.seats
```

**solution using [`JSON_CONTAINS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-contains) and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_json-arrayagg)**

```
SELECT r.seats, JSON_ARRAYAGG(s.name)
FROM reserved r INNER JOIN seats s ON JSON_CONTAINS(r.seats, JSON_QUOTE(CONVERT(s.id, CHAR))) = 1
GROUP BY r.seats
```

You can also use [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html) to solve this:

```
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(IFNULL(s.name, ''))
FROM reserved r, JSON_TABLE(
  r.seats,
  "$[*]" COLUMNS (
    id CHAR(50) PATH "$"
  )
) AS rr LEFT JOIN seats s ON rr.id = s.id
GROUP BY r.seats
```

**Note:** You can use `INNER JOIN` to remove the empty values. Instead of `GROUP BY r.seats` you should use a `id` column.

[**demo on dbfiddle.uk**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=7a5c7685893fef58e7d50e3dbddea8cb)

Comment: Thank you very much! I will go for Solution 3 which works like charm in MYSQL5.7. Maybe I will Update to MYSQL 8 soon, since the JSON TABLE function seems to be more efficient.